# Handling server shutdown

Tags: c#, sockets

I am pretty new to sockets in C# and I am trying to handle the server shutting down on the client, and I want the client to continously be connected, so when ever they can't connect they continously keep trying, and when the server shuts down, I want them to instantly try re-connecting again for when the server comes back up.

Program.cs [CLIENT]

```
using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Sythic
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.Title = "Sythic Client";
                Console.WriteLine();

                ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
                cm.Connect();

                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

ConnectionManager.cs [CLIENT]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Sythic
{
    class ConnectionManager
    {
        private Socket _socket;
        private Thread _thread;
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private bool _needsReconnecting;

        public ConnectionManager()
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect...");
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3459);

            try
            {
                _socket.Connect(ipep);

                _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTick);
                _timer.Interval = 1000;
                _timer.Enabled = true;

                _thread = new Thread(ReceivedData);
                _thread.Start();
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to server, retrying...");
                Connect();
            }
        }

        private void OnTick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_socket.Connected && _needsReconnecting)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The client is disconnect, we should start trying to re-connect now..");
                Connect();
                _needsReconnecting = false;
            }
        }

        private void ReceivedData()
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            int readBytes;

            while (true)
            {
                if (!_socket.Connected)
                {
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    buffer = new byte[_socket.SendBufferSize];
                    readBytes = _socket.Receive(buffer);

                    if (readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Received something...");
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    ServerClosed();
                }
            }
        }

        private void ServerClosed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh no, the server closed.. :/");
            // not sure what to do here, need to research how to disconnect, or does it disconnect automatically because no server? hmm...
            _needsReconnecting = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So whats the issue?
This line:

```
_socket.Connect(ipep);
```

in the Connect() method

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Once the socket has been disconnected, you can only reconnect again asynchronously, and only to a different EndPoint.  BeginConnect must be called on a thread that won't exit until the operation has been completed.

Comment: Based on the error message, you'll need to recreate the socket. Pull out the initialization for `_socket` into `Connect` rather than your constructor.